# REST API Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function

Tags: java, rest, jersey, noclassdeffounderror

I am creating a REST API in JAVA, and when trying to 'Run on Server' I get the following:

```
2016-08-09 14:26:23.366:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.16.v20140903
2016-08-09 14:26:23.741:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:FAILED AS Service: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.<init>(ResourceConfig.java:350)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:425)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:290)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:349)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:532)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:791)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.run(PreviewStarter.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.main(PreviewStarter.java:29)
Caused by: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Function
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
```

Any idea what could be causing this? 
I was able to run this earlier, and I haven't made any major changes since..

(Looking at few other similar questions, I have added the selenium jar and the guava jar too. But, that doesn't help)

Comment: You need to bundle guava (the Google java language utility library) in your WAR, it's not enough to put it on the classpath.